# AtmelStudio compiled code: How to optimize compiler

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, atmega, atmelstudio

For the code:

```
uint8_t count;

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect, ISR_NAKED)
{
    count++;
    reti();
}
```

The generated assembly is:

```
--- F:\atmel-prj\compiler-test2\compiler-test2\Debug/.././compiler-test2.c -----
{
00000048  PUSH R1       Push register on stack 
00000049  PUSH R0       Push register on stack 
0000004A  IN R0,0x3F        In from I/O location 
0000004B  PUSH R0       Push register on stack 
0000004C  CLR R1        Clear Register 
0000004D  PUSH R24      Push register on stack 
    count++;
0000004E  LDS R24,0x0100        Load direct from data space 
00000050  SUBI R24,0xFF     Subtract immediate 
00000051  STS 0x0100,R24        Store direct to data space 
}
00000053  POP R24       Pop register from stack 
00000054  POP R0        Pop register from stack 
00000055  OUT 0x3F,R0       Out to I/O location 
00000056  POP R0        Pop register from stack 
00000057  POP R1        Pop register from stack 
00000058  RETI      Interrupt return
```

Now, as I see it, at least one, and up to two push-pop pairs could be eliminated:

1. to save one push-pop, eliminate r24 by using r0 instead

   ```
   PUSH R1     Push register on stack 
   PUSH R0     Push register on stack 
   IN R0,0x3F      In from I/O location 
   PUSH R0     Push register on stack 
   CLR R1      Clear Register 
   count++;
   LDS R0,0x0100       Load direct from data space 
   SUBI R0,0xFF        Subtract immediate 
   STS 0x0100,R0       Store direct to data space 
   ...
   ```
2. See that no code is using r1 for 0 value, so use only r1 for all purposes.

   ```
   PUSH R1     Push register on stack 
   IN R1,0x3F      In from I/O location 
   PUSH R1     Push register on stack 
   CLR R1      Clear Register 
   count++;
   LDS R0,0x0100       Load direct from data space 
   SUBI R0,0xFF        Subtract immediate 
   STS 0x0100,R0       Store direct to data space 
   ...
   ```

Either of these save us precious bytes and microseconds.

Is there a way that I can put these or similar optimizations into the atmel studio toolchain/libraries somehow, so that my compiled code gets generated slightly better?
A lot of code surrounding interrupt and function calls, and some C to Assembly translations could be optimized a lot.

Comment: Is this for the atmel AVR architecture?  gcc can target AVR.  It's one of the available targets on http://gcc.godbolt.org/.  I have no idea how good Atmel's compiler is at optimizing other code, or whether it has options to enable optimization.

Comment: I have Atmel Studio 6 and it seems to have a gcc compiler in it. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, I'll look at gcc for avr target.

Comment: Did you enable optimization? Many IDEs default to some profile for debugging with optimization turned off.

Comment: Yes. This is with -O3. -O1 is also same. Also tested with debugging options turned off.

Comment: In answer to Peter, the gcc documentation at gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc and  documents supplied with Atmel Studio both have same text. They must be the same software.
Either way, I see that some fairly obvious optimizations were not done. So, either I dont understand code generation and optimizations well, or some obvious optimizations are not existing in toolchain. My question is primarily to find out if it is possible to change prologue and epilogue constructed by compiler somehow, without translating all my own code into assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I also found out that generated assembly code could be optimized. I was not using `-On` option by that time.
I found that the code of a called function (which takes a parameter in a register) ; copies it to the stack (to keep a clean copy as an 'automatic' C variable... which is in most case useless) AND FURTHERMORE copied back this value back to originating register !!! Whereas this register was just read before, and GCC should know it.

If you use Atmel Studio with default compiler, which is GCC, your binary code optimisation is depending on the toolchain behaviour, (and therefore, options specified on its command line).

To obtain a finest result, you can try to compile your source tree using avr-gcc directly (to setup options that Atmel Studio can't set for you).

Using another toolchain is another way to gain (theorically) finest results.
Anyway, i doubt any other toolchain will give an (overall) better result than GCC does.

Comment: I probably didn't heard about clang by that time ! Unsure if clang has an AVR backend anyway...